# Symfony2 - PUGXMultiUserBundle - Cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: symfony

I tried to install PUGXMultiUserBundle, now as I did all steps I tried to load the application (only the main location: `http://localhost/jpp/web/app_dev.php` ), but I always get the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class JPP\UserBundle\Entity\User in C:\xampp\htdocs\JPP\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken.php on line 155

I tried several things without success, please could you help me? Below you can find my Entity classes. I was able to create all the tables in the database with GIT. The rentity classes are located under: JPP/UserBundle/Entity. If you need more files please tell me... Thank you very much!!!

Roger

Abstract User Class:

```
<?php

namespace JPP\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"userprofile" = "UserProfile", "usercompany" = "UserCompany"})
 *
 */
abstract class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Class UserCompany

```
<?php

// src/jpp/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace JPP\UserBundle\Entity;

use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userCompany")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "JPP\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "JPP\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class UserCompany extends User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="usertype", type="integer")
     */
    protected $userType;    

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="companyName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $companyName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="sector", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $sector;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amountOfEmployees", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $amountOfEmployees;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="turnover", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $turnover;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="companyLink", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $companyLink;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="facebookLink", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $facebookLink;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="twitterLink", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $twitterLink;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param integer $userType
     * @return UserType
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyName
     *
     * @param string $companyName
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setCompanyName($companyName)
    {
        $this->companyName = $companyName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCompanyName()
    {
        return $this->companyName;
    }

    /**
     * Set sector
     *
     * @param string $sector
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setSector($sector)
    {
        $this->sector = $sector;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get sector
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSector()
    {
        return $this->sector;
    }

    /**
     * Set amountOfEmployees
     *
     * @param string $amountOfEmployees
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setAmountOfEmployees($amountOfEmployees)
    {
        $this->amountOfEmployees = $amountOfEmployees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get amountOfEmployees
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAmountOfEmployees()
    {
        return $this->amountOfEmployees;
    }

    /**
     * Set turnover
     *
     * @param string $turnover
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setTurnover($turnover)
    {
        $this->turnover = $turnover;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get turnover
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTurnover()
    {
        return $this->turnover;
    }

    /**
     * Set companyLink
     *
     * @param string $companyLink
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setCompanyLink($companyLink)
    {
        $this->companyLink = $companyLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get companyLink
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCompanyLink()
    {
        return $this->companyLink;
    }

    /**
     * Set facebookLink
     *
     * @param string $facebookLink
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setFacebookLink($facebookLink)
    {
        $this->facebookLink = $facebookLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get facebookLink
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFacebookLink()
    {
        return $this->facebookLink;
    }

    /**
     * Set twitterLink
     *
     * @param string $twitterLink
     * @return Company
     */
    public function setTwitterLink($twitterLink)
    {
        $this->twitterLink = $twitterLink;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get twitterLink
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTwitterLink()
    {
        return $this->twitterLink;
    }

}
```

Class UserProfile

```
// src/jpp/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace JPP\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use PUGX\MultiUserBundle\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="userProfile")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "username", targetClass = "JPP\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields = "email", targetClass = "JPP\UserBundle\Entity\User", message="fos_user.email.already_used")
 */
class UserProfile extends User
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="usertype", type="integer")
     */
    protected $userType;  

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $foreName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $surName;    

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $street;  

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $plz;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $place; 

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $phone;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $mobile;  


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }   


    /**
     * Set userType
     *
     * @param integer $userType
     * @return UserType
     */
    public function setUserType($userType)
    {
        $this->userType = $userType;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userType
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUserType()
    {
        return $this->userType;
    }

     /**
     * Set foreName
     *
     * @param string $foreName
     * @return ForeName
     */
    public function setForeName($foreName)
    {
        $this->foreName = $foreName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get foreName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getForeName()
    {
        return $this->foreName;
    }

     /**
     * Set surName
     *
     * @param string $surName
     * @return SurName
     */
    public function setSurName($surName)
    {
        $this->surName = $surName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSurName()
    {
        return $this->surName;
    }

     /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     * @return Street
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

     /**
     * Set plz
     *
     * @param string $plz
     * @return PLZ
     */
    public function setPlz($plz)
    {
        $this->plz = $plz;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get plz
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlz()
    {
        return $this->plz;
    }

     /**
     * Set place
     *
     * @param string $place
     * @return Place
     */
    public function setPlace($place)
    {
        $this->place = $place;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get place
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPlace()
    {
        return $this->place;
    }    

     /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     * @return Phone
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

     /**
     * Set mobile
     *
     * @param string $mobile
     * @return Mobile
     */
    public function setMobile($mobile)
    {
        $this->mobile = $mobile;

        return $this;
    }

     /**
     * Get mobile
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getMobile()
    {
        return $this->mobile;
    }


    //public function __construct()
    //{
    //    parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    //}
}
```

Comment: This article might help http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't find anything! @VadimAshikhman: Does it bring something when I post more classes. I am searching now the whole day, but I can't find the mistake...

Answer (score 0):

The error says:

`Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class JPP\UserBundle\Entity\User in C:\xampp\htdocs\JPP\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken.php on line 155`

It means that Symfony tries to instantiante your `User` class (e.g. new User()) but fails because this class is abstract. So, just remove abstract definition.

Replace

`abstract class User extends BaseUser`

with

`class User extends BaseUser`